# How to get the price from 2 different templates using xpath or bs4?(python, web scraping)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have two templates with 2 different prices. For the first template the price has the id priceblock_ourprice and it printed correctly but for the second template it doesn't print the price. How can I print the price in csv? You can use
xpath or beautiful soup. The problem of this code is on the first try/except statement. I attached the code and the output(csv). I will appreciate any help.

THIS IS THE OUTPUT(CSV)

[image]

```
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from lxml import html

links = [
      'https://www.amazon.com/Stock-Your-Home-Spinning-Organizer/dp/B00424ILAQ/ref=sr_1_4012/138-3260504-2979110?s=bedbath&ie=UTF8&qid=1520585702&sr=1-4012&keywords=-sdfg',
      'https://www.amazon.com/Seward-Trunk-College-Footlocker-SWD5120-10/dp/B004835DI4/ref=sr_1_3?s=furniture&ie=UTF8&qid=1520407190&sr=1-3&keywords=-hgfd'
]
proxies = {
    'http': 'http://218.50.2.102:8080',
    'https': 'http://185.93.3.123:8080'
}

def get_information(driver,urls):
    with open('csv/sort_products.csv', "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as infile:
        writer = csv.writer(infile)
        writer.writerow(['Price',  'Link'])

        for url in urls:
            driver.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")

            try:
                price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@id="color_name_0_price"]/span').text

            except:
                price='No price v1'
                print('No price v1')

            try:
                price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@id="priceblock_ourprice"]').text
            except:
                price='No price v2'
                print('No price v2')

            writer.writerow([ price, url])
            print(f'{url}\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server="%s"' % ';'.join(['%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in proxies.items()]))

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\Andrei-PC\Downloads\webdriver\chromedriver.exe",
                              chrome_options=chrome_options)
    get_information(driver,links)
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Try `price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@id="color_name_0_price"]/span | //span[@id="priceblock_ourprice"]').text`

Comment: It gives blank for the cell that should print the second price.

Comment: That's because there are no nodes with `@id="priceblock_ourprice"` on page

Comment: Can you please post the correct code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I checked both urls using my browser, and it looks like in second one there is no `span` with id `priceblock_ourprice`.  So of course `driver.find_element_by_xpath` can't find apropriate span.

However I can find this span: `<span class="a-size-base a-color-price offer-price a-text-normal">$62.26</span>`

Perhaps the content of the page server by amazon is different when you use your browser and different when running selenium (because of cookies for example). Please double check source of page you got in selenium.

Comment: For the second try/catch it gives the price for the template that has priceblock_ourprice but the problem is on the first try/catch (the second template). Can you please run the code to see the output(csv) or can you post the code?

Comment: The $62.26 is the price for the used product. I print the price $66.95 I think this is the price. Below Available from these sellers.

Comment: C'mon, we will not rewrite your code. It's not a code fixing service. Read answers and comments and fix it yourself. If you still have any doubts or questions just ask them clearly so that we understand it.